# Bash Script how to create a directory for a user which username consist of two words

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a bash script that asks for a username and a password. Based on the provided name and the password the script will create a user directory in /home for the user. Inside the directory a user file is also created.

**Problem:** If a user enters a username consisting of two words (like "Carl Eric") it creates two different directories named Carl and Eric.
I want the script to create only one user directory with the name Carl OR Eric.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#create user script
clear
read -p "Provide username: " u_name
read -s -p "Provide password: " u_password
echo "Creating your working directory and file!!!!"
cd /home/
mkdir ${u_name}_d
cd ${u_name}_d
touch ${u_name}_f
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you expect an input  string to contain spaces and you want to treat it as a single string, try to enclose it in double-quotes.

```
mkdir "${u_name}_d"
```

Comment: I'd add that you cannot be wrong by always adding double quotes around any variable expansion.